# How can I minimize this expression to a product of sums using rules of Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

The expression is : AD' + A'B + C'D + B'C. Any hint or something would be more than awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic here. Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+AND+NOT+D+OR+A+AND+NOT+B+OR+C+AND+NOT+D+OR+B+AND+NOT+C), I got (A OR B OR C) AND (A OR NOT C OR NOT D) AND (NOT B OR NOT C OR D) but not the intermediate transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, Law of distribution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+AND+b%29+OR+%28c+AND+d%29
What you want is the CNF (Conjunctive Normal Form) instead of DNF.